# Creating a job using curl with config.xml will have the code under Execute shell/Pipeline section in single line without indentation

Tags: jenkins, curl, config, jobs

I created a freestyle project using curl command and the execute shell section has the code in a single line without newline or indentation. How to get the code in the section in original format?

Eg: Original code under execute shell section:

```
 if [ a == 0 ]; then
   bash a.sh
 else
   bash c.sh
 fi
```

In the new job created using the above job's config.xml, the execute shell section looks:

```
if [ a == 0 ]; then bash a.sh else bash c.sh fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
    Add "--data-binary" when using the curl to create the job.
    Eg: curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" --data-binary @test.xml "http://user:api@ip:port/jenkins/createItem?name=test1"